# The class of cardinal numbers is well ordered

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm looking for a proof that the class of cardinal numbers is well ordered under the order relation $|A|\leq |B| \Leftrightarrow$ exists an injection $f:A \to B$.

In fact, I've found a very beautiful proof in an article, but I think it's not the standard one.

Comment: It follows immediately from the fact that the class of ordinals is well-ordered.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You need the well-ordering theorem too.

Comment: @Andrew: My base system is always ZFC.

Comment: @Ricardo, please give a link to that article and its proof.

Comment: @DonAntonio, http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1954-005-02/S0002-9939-1954-0060558-3/S0002-9939-1954-0060558-3.pdf

Comment: Muito obrigado, @RicardoCorreadaSilva

Comment: Cute argument.${}$

Answer (score 0):

There are several standard arguments here:

1. We define the $\aleph$ by transfinite induction as a function from the ordinals. That means that there is a surjection (in fact bijection) between the cardinals and the ordinals. Therefore the aleph numbers are well-ordered.
2. We define $\aleph_\alpha$ to be the cardinality of the $\alpha$ initial ordinal. Therefore, we treat the alephs as ordinals. A subclass of the ordinals is always well-ordered.